# How To Enabling Copy and Cut Operations on Java Disabled Field

Tags: java, swing, keyevent, disabled-input

I'm developing a software where client request all disabled text field should be allowed to do text selection, cut and copy operations. But now unable to proceed due to some issue faced. The input field that fit the requirements should be a read-only Text Field that able to do text selection and copy/cut through ctrl+c and when clicking on the Text Field it should not trigger any Focus/Action Listener.

Previously all disabled component is disabled through

> component.setEnabled(boolean)

But in this way, all disabled fields are not able to do text selection, cut and copy operations. I had tried few ways to enable copy and cut operations but found out the component is not processing any key event in this state, its seem like related to **Component.enableEvents(long)** I suspect this method will allow the container to dispatch the **KeyEvent** to the component but this method is not accessible from my project.

So I changed all the component to use

> JComponent.setEditable(boolean)

But the problem with this method is, all the disabled components will trigger ***FocusListener***, this should not happen because all the disabled fields should be read-only and have zero impact on other existing fields. Is there a way to enable the cut and copy operations without having the ***FocusListener*** to be trigger by using **setEditable** or there are other easier way?

*(And anyone can help to explain how the event from the component is caught and dispatch? Include how the java do the checking when the keyEvent should/should not dispatch to child component and is there a way we can bypass those checking and allow the component to processKeyEvent when the field is disabled).*

Comment: Why is the focus event a problem?

Comment: @MauricePerry, because i dont want the focus event to be trigger when user select the text for copy, some of the focus event is to perform data population/computation, but these population and computation should do only if the input field is enabled (and is huge effort to change all the focus listener to check is field isEditable before process the focusevent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but these population and computation should do only if the input field is enabled

Why is that an issue?

If you use common listener shared by all components then you just add a check to see if the component is editable.

If you use individual listeners for each component then you don't add a listener to the component if it is not editable.

I'm missing why this is a huge effort.

> how the event from the component is caught and dispatch?

You might be able to use a custom `KeyboardFocusManager`. Maybe override the `dispatchEvent(...)` method to prevent the dispatching of events in your specific cases.

Comment: Thanks for replying my question, because the application is huge and its maintained by different developers and the listener is not a common listener different input field had a different listener and where/when the listener is added to the component also depending on the requirements. Now I'm working on the Event Queue and also EventQueueDelegate but faced some other issue. Do you have any example code or document about those java event handling?